# Передать значение переменной из одной функции в другую

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, python-3.8

Есть две функции `func1` и `func2`. В `func1` происходит определение нескольких переменных и присвоение им значений. Функция `func2` должна работать с одной из переменных функции `func1`. Такой код не работает.

```
class C(object):
    def func1(self):
        a = "test"
        b = "test2"
    def func2(self):
        if a == "test":
           print(a)
d = C()
d.func1()
d.func2()
```

Вкладывать `func2` в `func1` нельзя. Но, если сделать `переменную а` глобальной, то все прекрасно работает.

```
class C(object):
    def func1(self):
        global a
        a = "test"
        b = "test2"
    def func2(self):
        if a == "test":
           print(a)
d = C()
d.func1()
d.func2()
```

Делать переммые глобальными - это неправильно, не так ли? Как передать значение переменной из одной фукции в другую, не делая её глобальной?

Comment: не очень понятно, что вам нужно сделать. Но очевидно для таких целей и придумали `return`

Comment: В первой функции нескольким переменным присваиваются значения. Во второй нужно проверить значение одной из переменных первой функции, и в зависимости от результата выполнить некое действие.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте поля класса, они для этого вполне подходят. К ним можно обращаться через `self.`:

```
class C(object):
    def func1(self):
       self.a = "test"
       self.b = "test2"
    def func2(self):
        if self.a == "test":
           print(self.a)
d = C()
d.func1()
d.func2()
```